# iterator in a 2Dimensional Map

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, nested

I would like to know how can I iterate in a 2Dimensional HashMap? I am creating an Object TrueStringMap2D that does the following: It will be a map 2D, i mean 2 keys and one value.

But the iterator implemented here is not functional.. i didnt know how to redefine the Iterator method in TrueStringMap2D :S (if possible should be remove in the iterator() functional)
Anyone can help? 
Thankyou very much!!

Comment: [I don't think SO wants to read all of that.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/175248)  If you can whittle down your code to fit with the scope of your question, that would be a huge benefit.

Comment: I would like to redefine the iterator mothod that will iterate over a map that contains a nasted map. (With the class Entry that i posted)

Comment: I answered it for the values, not the entries. You'll have to adapt my answer to solve it for entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll reinterpret the question into something similar that I enjoy answering, and then hopefully the answer to that question is useful to you.

Here's the question I'll answer:

> How do I write an iterator that iterates over all values in a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`?

This is how I would solve it:

```
class TwoDimIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    Iterator<Map<String, String>> outerIter;
    Iterator<String> innerIter = Collections.<String>emptyList().iterator();

    public TwoDimIterator(Map<String, Map<String, String>> twoDimMap) {
        outerIter = twoDimMap.values().iterator();
        advanceInner();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return innerIter.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
         String toReturn = innerIter.next();
         advanceInner();
         return toReturn;
    }

    private void advanceInner() {
        while (!innerIter.hasNext()) {
            if (!outerIter.hasNext()) {
                innerIter = Collections.<String>emptyList().iterator();
                return;
            }
            innerIter = outerIter.next().values().iterator();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

**Test code:**

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a map
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> twoDimMap =
                new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

        // Fill it
        Map<String, String> innerA = new HashMap<String, String>();
        innerA.put("1", "A1");
        innerA.put("2", "A2");

        Map<String, String> innerB = new HashMap<String, String>();
        innerB.put("1", "B1");
        innerB.put("2", "B2");

        twoDimMap.put("A", innerA);
        twoDimMap.put("B", innerB);

        // Create an iterator for the values:
        Iterator<String> twoDimIter = new TwoDimIterator(twoDimMap);
        while (twoDimIter.hasNext())
            System.out.println(twoDimIter.next());

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A2
A1
B2
B1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! But its a homework, and the professor told us that we shouldn t use external classes.. We should just redefine that iterator method. Can you adapt it please to my TrueStringMap2D? Its just a method.. Thats why i posted the interface (that contains the class Entry, that we will use just for the iterator method) and my TrueStringMap2D.. Can you understand the code? Its the last method that i should implement.. Thanks!!

Comment: If it's homework I think I'll leave the remaining steps for you to solve. :)

Comment: but it doesn t return the 3 values  (key1, key2, value) of each entry... it returns just the values..:S

Comment: Right... To make it iterate over entries is actually a trivial change so I'll leave it to you. It is homework after all.

Comment: but there's a problem already bey next().. eclipse says that the return type should be casted to Entry, and when I do that, error by the return variable "toReturn" should be casted to Entry, or String. if I cast it to String i will have the same problem as above, when I cast it to Entry, "innerIter.next();" erro: toReturn should be String... :S I have to return it before 00:00 :SS any other idea? Sorry