# Map.Entry redefinition, for iterator of 2 Dimensional Map

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, nested

We have a homework, to implement a class, that creates an Object that will be a 2Dimensional Map of Strings. `centralMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>`. The professor gave us an interface, that contains the methods that we should redefine, like the put method (`public String put(final String row, final String column, final String value)`) the get method (`public String get(final String row, final String column)`) and some other methods.. and the one that i couldn't redefine, is the iterator method.. In the interface that he gave, there was a class Entry, that he said, we ll use it just for the iterator method! But I have no idea what should we do with it.. Here is the class Entry, and the iterator method that we should redefine(implement):

```java
final class Entry
{
    /** First Key. */
    private final String key1;

    /** Second Key. */
    private final String key2;

    /** Value. */
    private final String value;

    /** Cponstructor for a new Tripel.
     * @param key1 First Key.
     * @param key2 Second Key.
     * @param value Value.
     */
    public Entry(final String key1, final String key2, final String value)
    {
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getFirstKey()
    {
        return key1;
    }

    public String getSecondKey()
    {
        return key2;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(final Object anything)
    {
        if(anything == null)
            return false;
        if(getClass() != anything.getClass())
            return false;
        final Entry that = (Entry)anything;
        return Objects.equals(getFirstKey(), that.getFirstKey())
               && Objects.equals(getSecondKey(), that.getSecondKey())
               && Objects.equals(getValue(), that.getValue());
    }

    // CHECKSTYLE- Magic Number
    @Override public int hashCode()
    {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(getFirstKey());
        hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(getSecondKey());
        hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(getValue());
        return hash;
    }
    // CHECKSTYLE+ Magic Number

    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("(%s, %s, %s)", getFirstKey(), getSecondKey(), getValue());
    }

}
```

and the iterator method that we should redefine is this one: `@Override Iterator<Entry> iterator();` How should I proceed? I heard that we should implement a new class just for the iterator.. 
tell me if you need the class that I implemented, (and which implements the interface he gave) to know how i put the nested map in the other one etc.. because the nested map is just created in the put method.. in my constructor there s just the centralMap.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: I gave you plenty of hints in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484575/iterator-in-a-2dimensional-map I'm almost inclined to vote close for duplicate.

Comment: didnt know how to start.. :S didnt know how to use this Entry class which is contained by the interface he gave us.. :S Sorry! But thanks, thanks a lot for your help!!! and there was a problem already bey next().. eclipse says that the return type should be casted to Entry, and when I do that, error by the return variable "toReturn" should be casted to Entry, or String. if I cast it to String i will have the same problem as above, when I cast it to Entry, "innerIter.next();" erro: toReturn should be String...

Comment: okay, should can you tell me, what would be the solution for the next() method? eclipse is saying that there is a problem by the return type, it can't be "String"

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to create an method, that creates an `Iterator` of entries. Every `Entry` is unique, because of the used Maps. So you just need to do something like:

```
for entryMap in map do {
  entryMap get list of keysAndValues
  for keyValue in keysAndValues preppend this key
}
```

Comment: It is just pseudocode so the code has to be written by you. :P