# Managing nested maps with string keys

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, hashmap

Can I access my `nestedMap` in my iterator when the `nestedMap` is created in the `put()` method, like this:

```
@Override
public String put(final String row, final String column, final String value) {
    /**
     * Second map which is contained by centralMap, that contain Strings as
     * Keys and Values.
     */
    Map<String, String> nestedMap;

    if (centralMap.containsKey(row))
        nestedMap = centralMap.get(row);
    else
        nestedMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (!nestedMap.containsKey(column))
        counter++;
    centralMap.put(row, nestedMap);
    return nestedMap.put(column, value);
}
```

and the centralMap is declared as an Object-Variable,

```
private final Map<String, Map<String, String>> centralMap;
```

but instantiated just in the constructor, like this:

```
centralMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

the method i'm trying to implement is the remove method:

```
@Override
    public void remove() {
        for (Map<String, String> map : centralMap.values()) {
            map = centralMap.get(keyName);
            iteratorNested.remove();
            if (map.size() <= 0)
                iteratorCentral.remove();
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: related: [Map.Entry redefinition, for iterator of 2 Dimensional Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532779/map-entry-redefinition-for-iterator-of-2-dimensional-map)

Comment: Is it really a *nested* map? It looks like yet another method local variable to me.

Comment: Access in ***which*** iterator?  Show an example of what you mean please.

Comment: if you had such a Map, centralMap<String,Map<String,String> and a nestedMap as described above, created just in the put method, how would you access it? you can do a for-each loop, like `for(Map<String,String> map : centralMap.values())` map = ... but when i dont want to use a loop, must I change my method and make the nestedMap as an object-variable in my class or is there another way like centralMap.get(****), i don't know, any other solution to acces that nestedMap instanciated as above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking exactly, but I think this is a little easier to read:

```
@Override
public String put(final String row, final String column, final String value) {
    /**
     * Second map which is contained by centralMap, that contain Strings as
     * Keys and Values.
     */
    Map<String, String> nestedMap = centralMap.get(row);
    if (nestedMap == null) {
      nestedMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
      centralMap.put(row,nestedMap);
    }

    if (!nestedMap.containsKey(column))
        counter++;
    centralMap.put(row, nestedMap);
    return nestedMap.put(column, value);
}
```

I can't quite understand what you're doing in the second stanza, so can't help you improve that.  And I don't see an iterator as referred to in your question.

You're making me guess, but maybe ELSEWHERE in your program (it would really help to see more code, and a specific function prototype or statement of behavior you're seeking) you want to be able to iterate through the contents of the `centralMap` instance, and nested instances of `nestedMap`.  Yes you can.

```
public void iterateOverAllNested()
{
   for (Map.Entry<String,Map<String,String>> nested : centralMap) {
     final String centralKey = nested.key();
     final Map<String,String> nestedMap = nested.value();
     System.out.println("Central map row/column: "+centralKey);
     for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : nestedMap) {
       System.out.println(" key="+entry.key()+", value="+entry.value());
     }
   }
}
```

Note that this smells.  Nested maps of untyped `String`s are probably wrong.  Any chance you've been writing Perl recently?  I suggest you write a second SO question asking about a good data structure for your specific problem.  You can include this code as your starting place, and folks will likely offer a cleaner solution.

Comment: From OP's earlier question: "We have a homework, to implement a class, that creates an Object that will be a 2Dimensional Map of Strings."

Comment: @Marko: I guess I'll take my hat and go home.

Comment: this is the method im trying to implement:
@Override
  public void remove() {
   for (Map<String, String> map : centralMap.values()) {
    map = centralMap.get(keyName);
    iteratorNested.remove();
    if (map.size() <= 0)
     iteratorCentral.remove();
   }
  }